# Cannot convert from Class<SpringRunner> to Class<? extends Runner>

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am getting the below compiler error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<SpringRunner> to Class<? extends Runner>
```

From this code:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
public class ReservationEntityTest {
```

I don't understand the error `Class<SpringRunner>` has `SpringRunner` that extends `Runner`.
What am I missing?.

Comment: Is the class that is imported `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner` or is it another class that is actually being imported?

Comment: This is the code https://github.com/civilian/java-spring-learning/blob/master/spring-tdd/producer/src/test/java/com/example/producer/ReservationEntityTest.java

Comment: Remove your `junit` dependency from the `pom.xml`. You are using an ancient version. The `spring-boot-starter-test` includes all dependencies needed. I would even  suggest to remove the `@RunWith` and use the `@Test` from JUnit5 (the `@DataMongoTest` already shouldinclude the `@ExtendWith` from JUnit5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual response was the one of @M. Demiun in the comments;

"Remove your junit dependency from the pom.xml. You are using an ancient version. The spring-boot-starter-test includes all dependencies needed. I would even suggest to remove the @RunWith and use the @Test from JUnit5 (the @DataMongoTest already shouldinclude the @ExtendWith from JUnit5."